# hidden columns are still shown in my browser, what's the problem?

Tags: html, excel, ms-office, hidden-field

I have an excel worksheet with some hidden columns.

I want to export it as a webpage, so I save that with html format but when I open it in my browser(IE and chrome), the hidden columns are still displayed.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could probably write CSS on top of the exported HTML file. I tried to export excel as web page and I could see that the hidden field is visible on chrome.

Comment: read about [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), this will help you hide the columns which you dont want to show.

Comment: Try "Internet Explorer" to open it, I use it in other system and it works, But in my system there is still some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find the **nth** column you want to hide and apply CSS like below. Make sure your CSS is inside the `<style>` block;

In the below example, I am hiding the second column.

Read more about [nt-child CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible Header</td>
      <td>Hidden Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visible Column</td>
      <td>Hidden Column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: display is none for the columns that are hidden, but it seems they doesnt work in my browser. I open this html file in other system and the hidden columns didnt display in them, I think there is some problem with my browser, maybe I have to change some setting.

Comment: Post the code generated for the **hidden column** to guide further.